# Authenticating with Google API library for Java to Google cloud

Tags: java, google-cloud-sdk

I am attempting to create some GCP VMs using the API client libraries for Java, but the examples that I have seen seem to be old. I started with this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/cmdline/src/main/java/ComputeEngineSample.java but it looks like the `GoogleCredential` class is deprecated. 
After some research I came up with this code

```
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
        if (credentials.createScopedRequired()) {
            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
            scopes.add(ComputeScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
            scopes.add(ComputeScopes.DEVSTORAGE_READ_WRITE);
            credentials = credentials.createScoped(scopes);
        }
        Compute compute = new Compute.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
            .setApplicationName("et").build();
        Compute.Instances.List instancesList = compute.instances().list("<GCP-PROJECT>", "us-central1-a");
        InstanceList executedOperation = instancesList.execute();
```

Next, I set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path of my service account json file and ran my code, but it fails with a `401 Unauthorized` error. The partial message is this

```
"message" : "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

The examples that I see are for other Google products like Storage, Pubsub etc, but I cant find any relevant example on how to use my credentials to invoke some operations on a `Compute` service. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This should help: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/cmdline/src/main/java/ComputeEngineSample.java

Comment: As you I think know, once you know how to use one Google service through an API Client Library, all the others function similarly. Google is moving towards Cloud Client Libraries but Compute Engine has not (yet) made the cut.

Comment: Thank you. But I had already looked at those (please see my original post). The example in that repo is using deprecated classes like GoogleCredential and the parameters to Compute.Builder is wrong. So I’m still stuck.

Comment: I just tried this for you and the code works for me

Comment: I was able to make it work with your suggestion, but there are still some issues. As I mentioned before `GoogleCredential` is a deprecated class, and the compiler issues a warning. However, this part puzzles me - The `Compute.Builder` constructor takes a `HttpTransport, JsonFactory, HttpRequestInitializer` - but passing in a `GoogleCredential` seems to work. Any idea why?

Comment: I'll update the answer using `google-auth-library`. I don't write much Java and so I'm not sufficiently familiar with the Google auth libraries in Java.

Comment: Perfect - `HttpRequestInitializer` - that was the missing piece that I needed. Thank you so much

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the Google sample and it works for me.

I abbreviated it to only enumerate instances.

```sh
PROJECT=
ZONE=
INSTANCE=
ACCOUNT=

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud alpha billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create an instance to enumerate
gcloud compute instances create instance-1 \
--project=${PROJECT}  \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--machine-type=f1-micro \
--image-family=debian-10 \
--image-project=debian-cloud \
--preemptible

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ./${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Overly broad permissions but...
gcloud projects  add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/compute.admin

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./${ACCOUNT}.json
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.dazwilkin.gce.App"
```

yields (edited for clarity):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.dazwilkin.gce:gce >------------------------
[INFO] Building gce 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ gce ---
Hello Freddie!
================== Listing Compute Engine Instances ==================
{
  "id" : "6020825766320745087",
  "kind" : "compute#instance",
  "name" : "instance-1",
}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.088 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-13T17:54:51-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dazwilkin.gce</groupId>
  <artifactId>gce</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>gce</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.9</source>
          <target>1.9</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.30.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-compute</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev235-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### Update: `google-auth-library`

From the `google-auth-library` docs:

```
import com.google.auth.Credentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class App 
{

    public static void main(String[] args )
    {

    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
    ...

    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer =
        new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
    Compute compute =
        new Compute.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    ...

}
```

with `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dazwilkin.gce</groupId>
  <artifactId>gce</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>gce</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.9</source>
          <target>1.9</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.30.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-compute</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev235-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
      <version>0.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
      <version>0.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```